# How To Customize "GITLAB" Profile?

Tags: github, gitlab, repository, readme

As we know, if we create a repository on **[Github](https://github.com)** by the exact name as username, then it's provide us a special feature that allow us to customize our Profile by **.README** file.

But, it there any way get this feature in **[GITLAB](https://gitlab.com)** also?

*[Note: I've already tried to do this by the same process as we do in Github. But it's not working for **[GITLAB](https://gitlab.com)**.]*

Comment: As far as I know, GitLab has no feature like this. There is nothing in the documentation nor any third party mentions of it

Comment: I also researched a lot about it. But didn't get any proper solutions. 
Let's see, if anyone can give me a suggestion.

Comment: This is not possible in GitLab -- yet. There is an open issue requesting this functionality with activity 4 days ago. You can find and follow it [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/232157). You can follow it by adding the `+1` reaction and subscribing to the issue. Also, if you're a paid customer you should contact your sales rep about this. It will help get the feature added faster than it would otherwise. There's a comment on the issue about a customer with 150 users wanting the feature already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [GitLab 14.5](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2021/11/22/gitlab-14-5-released/#add-personal-readme-to-profile) (November 2021): it should be possible now.

> ### Add personal `README` to profile
>
> You can now add a `README` section to your GitLab profile! This is a great way to tell others about, your interests, how you work, or anything else you want!
>
> To add a `README` section, create a new public project with the same name as your user account and add a new [`README` file](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/index.html#readme-and-index-files).
>
> The contents of that file are automatically shown on your GitLab profile.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/14_5/user_profiles_readme.png -- Add personal README to profile]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/#user-profile-readme) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/232157).

---

Note that [GitLab 15.9](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2023/02/22/gitlab-15-9-released/#discord-user-id-in-gitlab-profile) (February 2023) also includes:

> ### Discord user ID in GitLab profile
>
> Users can now add a link to their Discord user ID to their GitLab profile. This link is also returned through the Users API.
>
> Thank you [ideclon UK](https://gitlab.com/ideclon) for contributing!
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/15_9/manage-discord-profile.jpg -- Discord user ID in GitLab profile]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/users.html) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/390671).

Comment: thank you. I also got the update a few days ago.